# Can't use all wifi channels - Ubuntu 16.04, Asus 1215n, BCM4313

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, broadcom

I can't connect to my wifi (channel 13) and any 5Ghz network.

I found in polish forum information that removing packge `crda` will help. I made it but OS removed also kernel.

What i done:

- removed crda
- removed 3.19 kernel
- installed 3.13 kernel from live session (3.13 was default. I don't know why)
- set driver to b43 from driver menu
- iw reg set PL

It worked. But update manager gived me no kernel update notifications. So i installed 3.19 (marked as recommended) from kernel menu in update manager. when i boot into 3.19 it didn't worked. Channel 13 wasn't available.

Now i wanted fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. I have the same problem - no channel 13.

**Any idea how to make BCM4313 see channel 13 in Ubuntu 16.04?**

- [Wireless Info Script from USB Live Session](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23227197)
- [Wireless Info Script after many tries (described in Linux Mint forum)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23227215)

Comment: In topic in Linux Mint forums i've got few advices. None of them works but you can take a look (maybe it will help you). Link: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=211946

Comment: we dont care about mint ;-)

Comment: As i wrote - i tried both - **Ubuntu 16.04** and Mint 18. I posted link to Linux Mint Forum thread because informations there can be valueable.

Comment: Kernels v3.13 and v3.19 on Ubuntu 16.04? Are you sure about that? Custom kernels are unsupported here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your wireless adapter does not support 5 GHz. There is no way to connect to 5GHz networks with this adapter on any OS.

Also you need Broadcom proprietary drivers for this adapter. You can install them by

```
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Regarding channel 13, it may be blocked in your adapter if it was purchased in a country where this channel is not allowed, like the USA.